# Click hidden element using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, domxpath

I need to click on the fields bug, epic, feature, issue and task which appear on click the "+" icon.
I inspect each of the elements and the see the same common xpath highlighted in the image in developer tool.
How do i find the xpath of each of the elements highlighted and click on them using selenium webdriver?
[image]

```
<body class="lwp">
  <noscript><div class="absolute-fill flex-column flex-center"><h2>JavaScript is Disabled</h2><p>Please enable javascript and refresh the page</p></div></noscript>
  <input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="t6WnlqRwnH3QtDIOt2b3JiHWYI1V5vB3MheOCOTH7Fx6QaBNoXWz4k8P4luP9i7TYw70KVq4O2vuwa8DQRuLcdUxo_KKVjcmxorJTHAE3c42sdjYqojLZkOSNt1gad70mD0BBA2" />
  <div data-componentregion="page" class="full-size"></div>
  <div class="bolt-portal-host absolute-fill no-events scroll-hidden"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post `+` button html in text format as well `bug, epic, feature, issue and task` html in text format. Otherwise its very difficult to answer your query.Most importantly post some code trail as well.

Comment: List<WebElement> allItems= mydriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='bolt-portal-host absolute-fill no-events scroll-hidden']"));
System.out.println(allItems.size());
with the above code, i get the size as 1 while i was expecting the size to show up as 6(6 elements shown on UI on clicking the + icon) which means that i cannot use the mentioned xpath to click on the elements

Comment: Can you expand the div element and check what is there?

Comment: Can you share the HTML/DOM for the highlighted section(after clicking on + icon -> you get the highlighted section). In the screenshot of the Inspector -> you have highlighted the parent div(open the div - so that we can help you better). It would definitely contain some text -  Bug/Epic/Feature etc.

Comment: @Atul expanding the div tag doesn't show anything further. the same div tag shows up when i inspect each of the elements after clicking on the + icon

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle windows here because when you click "+" new window appearing with elements "bug","epic","feature",,,etc

- should be parent window and "epic",,,, are child window

Answer (score 0):

I could not identify unique xpath for the elements as all the elements had same xpath. using sikulix library solved my problem